# How I take a link from my JSON data and make it into an image via Ruby on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

```
<%= @schedule["data"][0]["visitorTeam"]["data"]["name"] %>
   <%= @schedule["data"][0]["visitorTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"] %>
<%= @schedule["data"][0]["localTeam"]["data"]["name"] %>
   <%= @schedule["data"][0]["localTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"] %>
```

Renders me

```
Rangers 
https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/teams/30/62.png 

Celtic 
https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/teams/21/53.png
```

I'm creating a schedule page, so I'd like to set up the view so that it just goes to the same area of the respective JSON for each image. How do I make it so that it recognizes the link and turns it into an image every time it goes to "logo_path"?

I've tried something like

```
  <%= image_tag <%= @schedule["data"][0]["localTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"] %> %>
```

but it didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `<%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["localTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"] %>` ?

Comment: @eugen that worked! Knew it would be something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["localTeam"]["data"]["logo_path"] %>`

No need of an extra `<%=`.